# Joining 2 tables while getting the 90th percentile of one table's values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, percentile

I have three tables to deal with.
These are the sample tables.

[image]

I want to get the 90th percentile of each '**operation**' in **STTR** table based on the data in '**value**' column.
And that also i want only during a time duration.
For that requirement i have written this query.

```
select DISTINCT STTR.OPERATION , 
        PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STTR.VAL ASC)
        OVER (PARTITION BY STTR.OPERATION) 
         as "90th Percentile"
        from STTR
 WHERE STTR.TIME > (SELECT EXE.START FROM EXE WHERE EXE.ID = 1001) 
 AND
 STTR.TIME < (SELECT EXE.END FROM EXE WHERE EXE.ID = 1001)
```

This gives me a result with list of operations and their 90th percentile. Like this
[image]

Now i want to add the columns of the TSS table also into this result and get this kind of result.
[image]

I tried joining the two tables but then when i added the percentile calculating part with the where clauses it gave me sql errors.

```
ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 10
```

This is the method i tired.

```
SELECT  TSS.ID,
        TSS.STEP,
        TSS.VAL1,
        TSS.VAL2,
        TSS.VAL3,
        (select DISTINCT STTR.OPERATION , PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STTR.VAL ASC)
        OVER (PARTITION BY STTR.OPERATION) 
         as "90th Percentile"
        from STTR
       WHERE STTR.TIME > (SELECT EXE.START FROM EXE WHERE EXE.ID = 1001) 
 AND
 STTR.TIME < (SELECT EXE.END FROM EXE WHERE EXE.ID = 1001))
      as Percentile                  
FROM TSS
JOIN STTR on STTR.OPERATION = TSS.STEP
WHERE TSS.ID = 1001;
```

Is this result possible to achieve if so could you guide me through how to achieve it.

Comment: maybe because you are selecting 2 columns in the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, it gave me desired output for your examples.

```
select distinct sttr.operation, tss.val1, tss.val2, tss.val3,
    percentile_disc(0.9) within group (order by sttr.val asc) 
      over (partition by sttr.operation) as "90th Percentile"
  from sttr 
    join exe on exe.tstart < sttr.time and sttr.time < exe.tend
    join tss on sttr.operation = tss.step
  where exe.id = 1001 
  order by operation
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b730b/1)</sup>

I renamed column names "start" and "end" to "tstart", "tend", because these are Oracle reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you cannot select 2 columns in the select subquery. Try this by moving the subquery to the from clause:

```
SELECT  TSS.ID,
        TSS.STEP,
        TSS.VAL1,
        TSS.VAL2,
        TSS.VAL3,
        t2.operation, 
        t2.percentile
FROM TSS, 
(select DISTINCT STTR.OPERATION , PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9), 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STTR.VAL ASC)
        OVER (PARTITION BY STTR.OPERATION) 
         as percentile
        from STTR) t2
JOIN STTR on t2.OPERATION = TSS.STEP
WHERE TSS.ID = 1001;
```